# How do I write arrays in pascal?

Tags: arrays, pascal

Is this program correctly written with the array?

```
Program Malaria_Outbreak (input,output);

Var
   BC:real;
   LO:real;
   count:integer;
   Num:integer;
   BloodTest:integer;
   Registration:integer;
   Clinic:string;
   DoctorFee:integer;
   Total:integer;
   NMB_Payable:real;
   Company:string;
   Name:string;
   Patient:Array[1..10] of string

Begin
   clrscr;
   BC:=(0.8);
   LO:=(0.7);
   Count:=(0);
   Num:=(0);
   BloodTest:=(Num * 700);
   Registration:=(500);
   Writeln('Please enter the name of the patient');
   Readln(Name);
   While (Name <> 'END')Do
     Begin
       For count:= 1 to 10 Do
         Begin
           Writeln('Please enter the clinic the patient attends');
           Readln(Clinic);
           If (Clinic = 'Type 1') Then
             Begin
               DoctorFee:=(800);
             End;
           If (Clinic = 'Type 2') Then
             Begin
               DoctorFee:=(1200);
             End;
           Writeln('The doctor fee for the patient is $',DoctorFee);
           Writeln('Please enter the number of blood tests the patient has had');
           Readln(Num);
           BloodTest:=(Num * BloodTest);
           Writeln('The blood test for the patient is $',BloodTest);
           TMB:=(Registration + DoctorFee + BloodTest);
           Writeln('The total medical bill for the patient is $',TMB);
           Writeln('Please enter the insurance company the clinic is affiliated with');
           Readln(Company);
           If (Company = 'Blue Cross') Then
             Begin
               NMB_Payable:=(BC * TMB);
             End;
           If (Company = 'LOJ') Then
             Begin
               NMB_Payable:=(LO * TMB);
             End;
           Writeln('The net medical bill for the patient is $',NMB_Payable);
       End;
   Readln;
   Readln;
End
```

Comment: I took the liberty to highlight your code. You can do this using the `{}` button.

Comment: Seems it is. Did you try compiling it? Also, please do clean it up a bit, there are a lot of trivial round brackets, and no internal indentation.

Comment: You ask 'is this ok'. Well, have you tried it? Doe you get errors?

Comment: The program looks ok, but you don't use the array.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good, but you might want to include the `;` after the datatype (`string`)

```
Patient : Array[1..10] of String;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in the code.

- Your code was not formatted. Especially the lack of indenting makes it hard to understand what's going on. (thanks to GolezTrol for fixing that)
- You're missing a semi-colon (;) after `Array[1..10] of string`
- Some `end;` statement is missing. Either `While (Name <> 'END')Do begin` or `For count:= 1 to 10 Do begin` should have a matching `end;` statement.
- Variable `Tmb` is not declared.
- Bloodtest will always be 0. It's initialized to 0, and the only time you write to `Bloodtest` is on this line: `BloodTest := (Num * BloodTest);`. That's probably not what you want to do.
- `DoctorFee` is uninitialized unless the user types `Type 1`  or `Type 2`. `NMB_Payable` has a similar problem.
- There's a variable `Count` that's initialized, but never used afterwards. Doesn't do any damage, but for readability I'd clean it up.

To answer your question: No, you're not using the array that's declared, and I don't think this program does what you want it to do.

If you explain what you're trying to accomplish, we can help you out with that.

Comment: To finish cleaning the code, you can also add that the two tests (on Clinic and Company) should use an If-Then-Else construct (instead of two If-Then) as if the first test succeeds, there is no need to do the second test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where it's writing to the array at all, nor where it would make any use of the array in the first place.  It's simply processing each item it gets, nothing is carried to be stored in an array in the first place.

It's also going to ask and bill each patient 10 times.  I've heard of double-billing but this is crazy!

You should always run your code and see what actually happens.  It's quite obvious you didn't.